# Behaviour of fread for quoted character columns in version 1.11.0

Tags: r, data.table

With the recent changes to `fread` in data.table Version 1.11.0 (May 1, 2018) seems to have trouble recognizing the correct values of `na.strings` with quoted character columns.

The default behaviour in conjunction with `fwrite` works just fine as described in the [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md) and shown in the working example below (`fread(fwrite(DT))==DT`).

However, if files are written using `fwrite(DT, quote = TRUE)` mimicing the behaviour of `write.csv` or writing the files directly using `write.csv`, `fread` seems to have problems detecting the correct strings specified in `na.strings` (shown in the non-working example below).

#### working example

```
dt <- data.table(A = c(1, 2, 3), B = c("a", "b", NA))
fwrite(dt, "testfile.csv")

# expected output
str(fread("testfile.csv", na.strings = c("a", "")))

Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ A: int  1 2 3
 $ B: chr  NA "b" NA
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Specification of `na.strings` seems to work just fine in this example using unquoted characters.

#### non-working example

Using the data.table `dt` from the example above:

```
fwrite(dt, "testfile_quoted.csv", quote = TRUE)  # mimicing write.csv
```

Here, specifying `na.strings = ""` also gives the expected result

```
str(fread("testfile_quoted.csv", na.strings = ""))

Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ A: int  1 2 3
 $ B: chr  "a" "b" NA
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

However, trying to specify `na.strings = c("a", "")` as in the example above gives an unexpected result:

```
str(fread("testfile_quoted.csv", na.strings = c("a", "")))

Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ A: int  1 2 3
 $ B: chr  "a" "b" NA
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

The expected result for column `B` should be `c(NA, "b", NA)` as in the working example above.

Specifying the quotes in `na.strings` directly also doesn't change the result for me.

```
str(fread("testfile_quoted.csv", na.strings = c("\"a\"", "")))

Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ A: int  1 2 3
 $ B: chr  "a" "b" NA
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

---

Am I missing something here?

I did not have these problems prior to version 1.11.0. Is there any way to restore the old behaviour of `fread` such that the consistency with old files written with `write.csv` is maintained?

---

#### Session Info

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Austria.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Austria.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Austria.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Austria.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.11.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.0 tools_3.5.0   
  [1]: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md
```

Comment: It might be related to [this issue on Github](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2586). I've posted a link to this question there.